# QGIS 3.10:SVG outline width not exported in pdf

Tags: qgis, svg

I am trying to use a self-written .svg in QGIS for a point layer. The .svg code is:

```
<svg>
<polygon points="0,2.7 2.7,0 5.4,2.7" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)"/>
<polygon points="0,2.7 2.7,5.4 5.4,2.7" fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)"/>   
</svg>
```

now, within QGIS:, the svg works as expected, having an adjustible line width and an adjustible fill colour in the lower part.

[image: layout wiew in QGIS]

However, when I try to export a map as pdf (rasterised), the outline width is not adapted [image: pdf screenshot, linewidth set to 0.2 mm with size of 5.5 mm]